# problems with ioException in sudoku code

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
 //Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 //at Sudoku.azar(Sudoku.java:94)
 //at Sudoku$EscuchadorStart.actionPerformed(Sudoku.java:106)
```

this is the error that shows after pressing the button start, 
the program compiles but it does not work when press the Button Start
I used a throws IOException in the methot but when I call that methot it says that I need
to catch the IOEXception

the text file juegos is a text file with 2 sudokus games, so it has 9 columns and 18rows

this is the code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;



public class Sudoku extends Frame{
private TextField[][] cuadrados=new TextField[9][9];
private Button start=new Button ("Start");
private Button check=new Button("Check");
private Button clear=new Button("Clear");
private Button exit=new Button("Exit");
private int[][] numeros=new int[9][9];
public int[][] auxiliar;




public Sudoku(){
    setSize(500,500);
    setTitle("Sudoku");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Panel pan=new Panel();
    pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9));
    add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Font myFont = new Font("ARIALBD",Font.BOLD,30);
    for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
            cuadrados[a][b]=new TextField();
            cuadrados[a][b].setFont(myFont);
            cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.pink);
            cuadrados[a][b].setForeground(Color.RED);

            pan.add(cuadrados[a][b]);
            if(a>=0&&a<3){
                if((b>=0&&b<3)||(b>=6&&b<9)){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
            if(a>=3&&a<6){
                if(b>=3&&b<6){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
            if(a>=6&&a<9){
                if((b>=0&&b<3)||(b>=6&&b<9)){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    Panel aux=new Panel();
    aux.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    aux.add(start);
    aux.add(check);
    aux.add(clear);
    aux.add(exit);
    add(aux, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    start.addActionListener(new EscuchadorStart());
    check.addActionListener(new EscuchadorCheck());
    clear.addActionListener(new EscuchadorClear());
    exit.addActionListener(new EscuchadorExit());
}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    Sudoku x= new Sudoku();
    x.setVisible(true);

}

public static int[][]  azar ()throws IOException{    
    int random= (int)(Math.random());
    BufferedReader text   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("juegos.txt"));
    String[] ayuda=new String[9];
    int lines=18;
    int[][] WhatReturn=new int[9][9];
    String aux="";

    for(int c=0;c<17;c++){

        aux=text.readLine();

        if(c==random*9){
            if(c==0){
                ayuda[c]=aux;
            }
            else ayuda[c-9]=aux;
        }

    }
    for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
            WhatReturn[a][b]=Integer.parseInt(ayuda[a].substring(b,b+1));
        }


    }       


    return WhatReturn;
} 
public class EscuchadorStart  implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent x) {
         try{
             int [][]auxiliar= azar();
         }
         catch(IOException e){
             //code to handle an IOException here
         }


        for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
                if(auxiliar[a][b]!=0){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setText(""+auxiliar[a][b]);
                    cuadrados[a][b].setEditable(false);
                }
                else;
            }
        }

        for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
                if(cuadrados[a][b].getText().equals("")){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class EscuchadorCheck implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x){
         for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
                if(cuadrados[a][b].getText().equals("")){
                    numeros[a][b]=0;
                }
                else numeros[a][b]=Integer.parseInt(cuadrados[a][b].getText());
            }
        }
         for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
                for(int c=b+1;c<9;c++){
                    if(numeros[a][b]!=0){
                        if(numeros[a][b]==numeros[a][c]){
                            cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        } 
         for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
            for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
                for(int c=a+1;c<9;c++){
                    if(numeros[a][b]!=0){
                        if(numeros[a][b]==numeros[c][b]){
                            cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }       
    }
}
    public class EscuchadorExit implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class EscuchadorClear implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x){
         for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
                cuadrados[a][b].setText("");
            }
        }
        EscuchadorStart y=new EscuchadorStart();
        y.actionPerformed(x);

    for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<9;b++){
            cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.pink);                
            if(a>=0&&a<3){
                if((b>=0&&b<3)||(b>=6&&b<9)){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
            if(a>=3&&a<6){
                if(b>=3&&b<6){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
            if(a>=6&&a<9){
                if((b>=0&&b<3)||(b>=6&&b<9)){
                    cuadrados[a][b].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You keep saying `IOException` but posted a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: And you're posting a heck of a lot of code, most of it completely unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent x) {
     try{
         int [][]auxiliar= azar();
     }
     catch(IOException e){
         //code to handle an IOException here
     }

     // etc
```

Your problem is here. Your `auxiliar` variable shadows the one of your instance; and in the code after that, you try and access your instance variable which is not initialized --> NPE.

Note: it is really bad practice to do nothing in the case of an IOException. Anyway, you probably meant to do:

```
try {
    auxiliar = azar();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // please handle that
}
```